# Call instance method from static time callback

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer within a class, and when this timer fires I want to call an instance method of this class. How do I access this from the static timer callback method?

```
private void ClassInstanceMethod()
{
}

public static void TimerFired(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Want to call ClassInstanceMethod() here
}

private void startTimer()
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerFired);
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

**Solved**
I had the misconception that `TimerFired` had to be static - which it does not.

Comment: well, you can't - why would you want to do that. I.e. what prevents from making your method static?

Comment: Or the TimerFired method non-static?

Comment: of course, but static methods often get the calling instance object as a parameter.

Comment: @Egil - Why is `TimerFired` `public` and `static`?

Comment: @carlosfigueira - thanks - I thought it had to be static...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I too had fallen upon that same misconception that the method called had to be static and it was causing me much frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The source parameter is the Timer object, and the ElapsedEventArgs object doesn't contain any reference to the instance of your class. As was discussed in the comments, you can make the TimerFired method non-static (i.e., instance), and from there you'll be able to safely call ClassInstanceMethod and other instance methods from the class.